# Is there a word to describe someone's willingness to commit horrific acts?

Tags: single-word-requests

**Example: "It used to be hard for him to take the life of an innocent, but over time his *[ability to commit horrific acts]* strengthened"**

Is there a word that specifically refers to the measurement of someone's ability to commit a horrific act without hesitation, mostly because they believe it to be necessary?

An example of a horrific act would be murdering an innocent for the purpose of a sacrificial rite because his cult demands it of him. Is there a word that describes his measure to do so?

Some words I've considered are "disregard" and "callousness" but neither seems to quite fit.

Comment: Which viewpoint are you asking about? *Depravity* might fit; but if it's a good thing then *resolve* would work instead. You might even find that something like *resolve* provokes a greater disgust in your readers than something less subjective.

Comment: I'm hoping for a neutral viewpoint to describe such an attribute in a person. It's to describe multiple characters, some of whom enjoy the wicked acts, others who feel like they have no choice but to do what must be done.

Both of your examples are close but don't quite offer the neutrality I'm looking for.

Comment: Over time, the person was [**desensitized**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/desensitize).

Comment: They are stonyhearted and display stonyheartedness

Comment: violent. tendencies.

Comment: Nice suggestions but still not quite fitting.